# How to stop semi-matched webpages from fully refreshing?

Tags: java, jquery, html, refresh, matching

I found this template online and i'm curious how a part of it works.  I'd like to apply the same method to a site i'm developing.

http://www.websitetemplatesonline.com/free-template/christmas-eve.html

Notice that when you click on the heading ARTICLES, only the content within the main box refreshes. Then if you click on READ MORE under the first entry, again only the info inside the main box changes yet the whole site does *not* refresh.

So I downloaded the free template package and looked at the HTML source and saw the code for both articles.html and article.html (the sub page) fully match.  The only difference to those pages is the info that's displayed upon clicking 'read more'.

I tried this method myself on the project I was working on, yet when you click 'read more', the entire page fully refreshes instead of just the info inside the box.

Any ideas on how this was done??

Comment: [<iframe>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: I didn't see any use of iframe used on those pages though.

Comment: Hmm...? `<iframe id="tframe" width="100%" frameborder="0" style="height: 439px;"...` seems to be at the top level. Are you viewing source of the top frame or just the source of the lower iframe?

Comment: I'm referring to the website template in the lower frame.  Ignore the upper frame.

Click on "ARTICLES" in the menu, then click on "READ MORE".  You will see the contents of the white frame (or box) changes, but the entire website does not refresh.

I copied the same style of this site, but my entire site refreshed when you clicked links.  I'm trying to figure out how they did this.  If two pages of code match, why would the entire thing refresh if only a small part changes (inside a frame, box etc)?